# How to get and print Jenkins console output in Python script

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-api

I am trying to trigger a jenkins job using python script with [`jenkinsapi`](http://pythonhosted.org/jenkinsapi/) module.

```
import jenkinsapi
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
J = Jenkins('http://localhost:8080')
J.build_job('testjob')
```

I want to print console output from jenkins job which gets triggered with this in my python script. Can someone suggest me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to get it in real time or is it good enough to get it when the build ends?

Comment: @ Tizki, I wanted it in real time and I was able to resolve it. Posting the answer separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it with real time logs getting dumped into /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/#job_title#/builds/#build_id#

Comment: what do you mean?